# Closed form of generating function

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

Find the closed form of the generating function of the sequence $\frac{{n \choose r}}{n^r \cdot (r+3)}$ where $n$ tends to infinity. I tried to make a sort of infinite gp to use infinite gp sum formula but I failed......

Comment: Hint: $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} \frac{x^r}{n^r}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\int_0^1 x^{r+2} dx = \frac{1}{r+3}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me in successfully finding the generating function!